# Get Attributes other than ID / Name

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

I am trying to write some VBA to input cell values into a website.

An example of the HTML is:

```
<input name="ctl00$CPH$c_7f0de753x200dx402bxb63bxd08cc4f3f1e0"
   type="text" 
   id="c_7f0de753x200dx402bxb63bxd08cc4f3f1e0" 
   field-name="Forename" 
   map="contact_Forename" validate="required: true">
```

I have succeeded using the ID and the Name shown below but these are liable to change, therefore I need to reference the map or field-name attributes in the HTML above.

```
Sub Registration()
the_start:
On Error GoTo The_End
Set objie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
objie.Top = 0
objie.Left = 0
objie.Width = 800
objie.Height = 600
objie.Visible = True

objie.navigate ("http://closerstill.circdata-solutions.co.uk/microsites/rfg/publish/PF2014/?source=websitetabpb")

Do

DoEvents

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        objie.Quit
        Set objie = Nothing
        GoTo the_start:

    End If

Loop Until objie.ReadyState = 4

objie.Document.getelementbyID("c_a5f795c9x0984x4bffxab24xae4ed7ccc093").Value = "Test"

The_End:
End Sub
```

Comment: Typically you'd use `getAttribute()` to read the values of specific attributes.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536429(v=vs.85).aspx  To use that to find a specific input you could use `getElementsByTagName("input")` and loop over the resulting collection until you find the element with the required attribute value.

Comment: Why do you suspect that `ID` attribute is more likely to change than the other attributes?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks Tim, I look into using a for each loop, would you be able to give me an example of how you would do it, I am a bit new to vb

Comment: @DavidZemens
It has already changed but the other two attributes above have remained the same.

Comment: Plenty of examples here on SO. E.g.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838276/excel-vba-getelementsbytagname-only-returning-the-last-input

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks

All sorted: Will add my solution above for anyone with a similar question

Comment: @user3554476 It's okay to answer your own question. I'd suggest removing the solution from the question and posting your own answer to  your question and accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Registration1()
the_start:
On Error GoTo The_End
Set objie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
objie.Top = 0
objie.Left = 0
objie.Width = 800
objie.Height = 600
objie.Visible = True

objie.navigate ("http://closerstill.circdata-solutions.co.uk/microsites/rfg/publish/PF2014/?source=websitetabpb")

Do

DoEvents

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        objie.Quit
        Set objie = Nothing
        GoTo the_start:

    End If

Loop Until objie.ReadyState = 4

Dim element As Object
Set Inputs = objie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")

For Each element In Inputs
If element.getattribute("field-name") = "Forename" Then
element.Value = "test"
End If

Next

The_End:
End Sub
```